# Save data of linq query for later comparison

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to save the data of a linq query in an object to compare to the updated fields after data updates to the sql tables. The problem is that every time I access the original linq query object we are seeing the updates there even though I'm using ToArray which I thought executes the query immediately and doesn't execute again when referring to that object. Here is my code:

```
dim db as New DBDataContext
Dim oldJobPart = (From jp In db.JobParts
                 Where jp.JobNum = 10214
                 Select jp).ToArray
```

UPDATE:

When the updates were done in the db object which is the same object used for the above query, then the oldjobpart would reflect the new changes. When we created a new object (db2) to update the database, the oldjobpart did not get updated.

So it seems that if we use the same db object to submitchanges() of an update, even though we don't touch the oldjobpart object and we used toarray to create oldjobpart, the oldjobpart object will still be updated. I guess the toArray doesn't totally cache the data and disconnect from the original database object? I would appreciate if someone could confirm this.

Comment: You need to create another new object and store your results there. Then you can access anything you need from the new object... Since its an array you can create a List Of whatever your data type is... Also turn Option Strict On it would help.

Comment: I tried that and it returned the same updated data. What syntax would you use to do that? Maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: @nlehman your syntax is ok, but you may need to have at least one class field and another one method fields: `Dim oldJobPart` must be defined as class field and then `Dim newJobPart` as method field where you do the query. After comparison, you updated `oldJobPart` with `newJobPart`

Comment: @nlehman that aside: codes that you use, sample inputs, expected outputs, and actual outputs may help people to reproduce your error which may lay in the scope beyond what you initially posted

Comment: @Ian our code is pages long and we were trying to find where to start looking for this error. I was first making sure that I'm not totally off the mark for thinking that toarray just saves a copy of the queried data to oldjobpart. I still don't really know the answer to that from the comments here.

Comment: @nlehman after `ToArray`, do you use `oldJobPart` by any way? Since LINQ is a delayed execution. It is possible for the LINQ to be not executed at all before it is needed. (though strictly speaking, `ToArray` should have taken cared of that case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your update is correct.

When you do the first query, it does indeed execute and store the results in an array.

The problem you are having is that the objects *within* the array are still attached to your database context - the array is just pointing at the objects cached in the `DbContext`. If you update a property of an object somewhere else in your code or in the `DbContext`, you are also updating the object the array is pointing to.

If you dont' want to create multiple contexts but want the objects in the array to be different fromte `DbContext`, a simple way around this is to use [`AsNoTracking()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.asnotracking(v=vs.113).aspx) so that the object is not cached in the `DbContext`:

```
Dim db as New DBDataContext
Dim oldJobPart = (From jp In db.JobParts
                 Where jp.JobNum = 10214
                 Select jp).AsNoTracking().ToArray
```

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. AsNoTracking() is not showing up in intellisense by me.